# How to convert a dataframe column of type string to list of type tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, tuples

have a df with type (str)

```
name       password

mark   (('name', 'value passed'),)

cuban  (('location', 'area geocode'),)
```

`(('name', 'value passed'),)` is a string

convert a dataframe column `password`of type str to list of type tuple

expected output :

```
tuples_password = [(('name', 'value passed'),),(('location', 'area geocode'),)]
```

tried this :

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.password]
```

Comment: Could you explain in detail about your expected output ?

Comment: @Mari edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Im a total noob and though Id give it a go.

```
df['tuple_field'] = [tuple(eval(i)) for i in df['password']]
tuples = [x for x in df['tuple_field']]
```

Output:

```
[(('name', 'value passed'),), (('location', 'area geocode'),)]
```